# Decode a string - Quote marks issue

Tags: python, encryption

I am supposed to decode the string below in a script I have made (it is a task from a webpage). In order to ensure that the decoded word will be correct, I can not change the string in any way. Since the quote marks affects the string, parts like `q90:;AI` is not a string, which results in a syntax error.

```
q0Ø:;AI"E47FRBQNBG4WNB8B4LQN8ERKC88U8GEN?T6LaNBG4GØ""N6K086HB"Ø8CRHW"+LS79Ø""N29QCLN5WNEBS8GENBG4FØ47a
```

Is there a way I can decode the encrypted message without changing it? As of now I am just getting syntax error when I define the string in a variable.

Comment: *Try pasting it in IDE and see for yourself.* ... No no, you hafta do it and paste the results here

Comment: Use single quotes to wrap it.

Comment: @BhargavRao the part which is not a string is marked with black in the string

Comment: There are no single quotes within the string, why not use those instead? Or make it a multiline string, with either single or double quotes?

Comment: @Selcuk Thanks man! So you are certain that it wont affect the decoding? You see, it takes like three hours to decode, so I want to make sure it is the correct string

Comment: Your question is not clear but yes, you can declare a Python string literal like `my_str = 'Here "I" am'`. The single quotes at the start and the end are _not_ part of the string.

Comment: Is the string you have shared with us the exact string that is on the webpage? If the string you're _really_ operating on has characters other than what we're seeing here, then there's no guarantee that anyone's solutions will work.

Comment: http://kodeklubben.github.io/python/kryptonott/kryptonott.html

Comment: @Kevin Yes, it is the exact same. How did you guys find the webpage? o.o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can surround the string with single quotes, since double quotes are used in the string already:

```
>>> print 'q0Ø:;AI"E47FRBQNBG4WNB8B4LQN8ERKC88U8GEN?T6LaNBG4GØ""N6K086HB"Ø8CRHW"+LS79Ø""N29QCLN5WNEBS8GENBG4FØ47a'
q0Ã:;AI"E47FRBQNBG4WNB8B4LQN8ERKC88U8GEN?T6LaNBG4GÃ""N6K086HB"Ã8CRHW"+LS79Ã""N29QCLN5WNEBS8GENBG4FÃ47a
>>>
```

Comment: Alright! You sure it wont affect the decoded messge?

Comment: @AndreasAmundsen yep, don't worry :)

Comment: Thank you very much! I will accept the answer asap! :D